# How to stop or prevent GDB from searching all symbols

Tags: gdb

I am running gdb on a very large project C++, something like 500k sloc's,  300k symbols.

Whenever I mistype a TAB, gdb will search for all those symbols, then present the helpful "Display all XX possibilities?"
Problem is that the search takes over a 1min, and gets mem usage up to over 4gb (not going down after that).

There must be a way to stop this behaviour in gdb. Can I disable the TAB for symbol resolution/completion?
Or limit the number of loaded/searched symbols? Or at least kill that search when it starts? Ctrl+C or anything doesn't work.

I'm using gdb 7.7

Answer (score 3):

> Can I disable the TAB for symbol resolution/completion?

You can disable all tab-completion (for all programs using GNU readline, including GDB) by putting this:

```
set disable-completion on
```

into `~/.inputrc`. Documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax).

I don't believe there is a way to disable tab-completion for symbols only.

Comment: Hmm thank you.

What i'd like precisely is disabling tab-completion solely for the global namespace. But i guess that's asking for too specific an option.